# 0100 в 100 числовые значения

Tags: php, математика

Подскажите пожалуйста, в функцию попадает число, с ним внутри происходят математические операции, есть ли способ из числа 0100 получить 100 не прибегая к конвертированию его в строку и обратно? Второй вопрос, почему 0100/10 = 6.4? Происходит побитовая операция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что нулем начинаются числа в восьмеричной записи.

Восьмеричное `0100` равно десятичному `64`.